# Desired capabilities depreciated, how to get it appium working with Android driver?

Tags: c#, android, selenium, appium, appium-android

I'm currently trying to start a automation project with Appium/Selenium and noticed that DesiredCapabilities are depreciated. Does anyone have a working example of a workaround or new implementation of this?

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Android;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Enums;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;

namespace LeaflyAutomation
{
    public class TC1
    {

        public AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL(sc_url), caps);

        public void InitDriver()
        {
            //No longer valid, need new driver setup
            DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

            caps.SetCapability("PlatformName", "Android");
            caps.SetCapability("appPackage"), "myapp file path");
            caps.SetCapability("appActivity", "com.demo.demofolder.activities.MainActivity");



        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: With Selenium WebDriver version 3.11.0, desired capabilities work absolutely fine in Appium along C#.

Answer (score 1):

> you are importing the wrong library for DesiredCapabilities.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
public class TC1
{

    public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    public void InitDriver()
    {

    DesiredCapabilities caps=new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("appPackage", "your app package name");
    caps.setCapability("appActivity", "your app activity name");
    caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Android phone");
    caps.setCapability("platform","Android");

    driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(
            "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);

    }
}
```

For more info visit [Step by Step Appium Tutorial for Beginners](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

```
DesiredCapabilities are depreciated in latest version , we can use AppiumOptions to pass device detail instead of DesiredCapabilities. 

                  AppiumOptions capabilities = new AppiumOptions();
                  capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("platformName", "Android");
                  capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("app", "APK_Path");
                  capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("udid", "Device_ID");
                  capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "Android");
                  capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("noReset", false);
                  driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```